# GridLayout with equal size for each element

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm trying to make a layout that is laid out like [this.](https://cdn2.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3586448/Android_Lollipop_Flashlight.png)
But I need the elements (the images) to have equal and full size to create the spacing between them and not use margins to space them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the required result with android TableLayout.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html)'s the developer link for TableLayout

Answer (score 0):

some times grid layout is not an answer. try 3 linear layout over each other like this its simple

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">

<Button
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_you_should_know"
    android:maxWidth="360dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_wounded_demon"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_maze_desert"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_working_with_darkness"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_weak_spot"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

also u can remove or add a button to each line using max width and height and dont forget to add layout_weight="1" its works me hope it work for u.

and for margins u could put picture in a bigger picture without background in PNG format.